# Issue regarding jquery dialog height & width increase

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

i was trying to increase height & width of jquery dialog but when i run my program height increased fine but width did not increase properly.

here is my program code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#opener2").click(function () {
            $("<div id='dialog2' />").dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff',
                draggable: true,
                resizable: false,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                }
            });

            $("#dialog2").dialog('open').show();
            setTimeout(function () {

                $("#dialog2").animate({
                    left: (($(window).width() - 400) / 2) + 'px',
                    top: (($(window).height() - 400) / 2) + 'px',
                    height: '400px', width: '400px'
                }, 200,
                function () {
                });

            }, 2000);
            return false;
        });

});
```

but when i increase the `height & width of .ui-dialog` instead of `#dialog2` then i saw dialog size increase properly but i do not want to play with `.ui-dialog` which is a part of jquery dialog.

so anyone can suggest me how to handle this situation as a result `#dialog2` height & width will increase properly.

### This way i sorted

```
setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery("#dialog2").dialog("widget").animate({
                    width: '400px',
                    height: '400px'
                }, {
                    duration: 200,
                    step: function () {
                        jQuery("#dialog2").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                    }
                });

            }, 2000);
            return false;
```

Comment: http://developer.happyr.com/libraries/jquery-happyr-dialog
http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-dialogs-using-ui-dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the animation? For simple resizing, you can use the `.dialog()`'s built in setter:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var dlg2 = $("#dialog2");
    dlg2.dialog("option", "width", ($(window).width() - 400) / 2);
    dlg2.dialog("option", "height", ($(window).height() - 400) / 2);
    // That next line is default anyway
    dlg2.dialog("option", "position", { my: "center", at: "center", of: window });
}, 2000);
```

---

EDIT:
If you want the animation, you could rely on your own `dialogClass` (noTitleStuff) instead of `.ui-dialog`, as (according to the documentation) this will be added to the "root element" of your dialog.
Animating based $('.noTitleStuff') instead will probably be your safest bet, that way you won't need to rely on the (possibly changing) internal class names and element hierarchies of the UI dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#opener2").click(function () {
        $("<div id='dialog2' />").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff',
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {}
        });

        $("#dialog2").dialog('open').show();

        setTimeout(function () {
            // Working resize, based on your own custom CSS class that you attach in the dialog creation
            $(".noTitleStuff").animate({
                left: (($(window).width() - 400) / 2) + 'px',
                top: (($(window).height() - 400) / 2) + 'px',
                height: 400,
                width: 400
            }, 200);
        }, 1000);

        return false;
    });
});
```

I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpwrn/

Comment: yes i want to increase height & width with the help of animate because a nice effect comes when we  increase height & width with the help of animate function.

Comment: can u provide the code for increase div size with the help of animate function but div will have right height. thanks